# Marking inbox items as read in api v2.2

Tags: feature-request, status-review, api-v2.2, inbox

I'm aware of [this question](https://stackapps.com/q/4107/3776), but it applied to an older (readonly) api version.
Given that API 2.2 is read/write, I figured this might be possible now.

**Is there any way for an application using the API to mark as read those items returned by the `inbox/unread` method?**

I would be inclined to think there is a way, given that I'm posting this from an android app which is capable of doing that. If there isn't, please consider this a feature request, the [`sx` client for Emacs](https://github.com/vermiculus/sx.el) will be considerably less useful without this.

Comment: Pretty sure the answer is still no.  Send me a comment reply and I'll double-check (Unless I forget by the time I get my next inbox items).

Comment: Nope. Only thing I've yet to try is to upvote an unread comment via the API.  If ***that*** doesn't mark the matching notice as unread, then there's a bug in the upvote logic.

Comment: @BrockAdams Yet another one then?

Comment: Oops. No. I'm done trying to find workarounds for this.  *You* should try checking the official app for an undoc'd api.

Comment: @BrockAdams OK, thanks a lot for your help. I'll ask the app's developer.

Answer (score 5):

This is not possible in api-2.2, but it might be made available in 2.3.

*Semi-source:*
I had an email exchange with someone from the android app team, who then talked to the api team. It's not on 2.2 but they're *"open to moving it to the 2.3 API release".*